# Webpack: how to include excluded node modules for AWS Lambda

Tags: node.js, webpack, node-modules

I've got a node module that no matter what doesn't bundle well when using webpack.  So the only way forward is to exclude this particular module from my webpack bundle.

However, i still have to include the unbundled module files in my package for deployment to my aws lambda.  I'm scratching my head about how to do this.  Can I get webpack to put only this module and it's dependencies in a seperate node_modules folder in my dist folder?  What's the best way to do this?

Comment: https://webpack.js.org/plugins/ignore-plugin/

Comment: Thanks @morganney,  But I'm not sure if this is what I'm looking for?  Could you provide a little more detail about how this will allow me to include the unbuilt modules in my dist folder?